# What does error 10054 during TCP read in j2me means?

Tags: http, java-me, tcp

What does error 10054 during TCP read in j2me mean?

I run a code in j2me Http Connection and got the above error
Why does it come?
I tried it for two codes

Answer (score 1):

10054 is a WinSock or Windows Socket API error code stating that "Connection was reset by the remote host." There can be different causes of this error. It is possible that the peer on the server was stopped unexpectedly. It is also possible that your app tried to connect to the correct address but on the wrong port. Anyway, this entry about [WinSock error 10054](http://geekswithblogs.net/Lance/archive/2007/08/07/Winsock-Error-10054.aspx) might help you in fixing your problem.